# Trying to identify book(s) with 'Gnomes' that moved too fast to be seen

Tags: story-identification

As a kid I read these stories about these "gnome" men who moved too fast to be seen by normal people (sometimes they'd see a blur). Because they lived so fast they only lived like 3 days but that was years to them. I believe "gnome" had alternative spelling too, because somehow they were different.

I remember in one of the books they had to stand really still to get a humans attention and talked about tying his shoes to trip him when he was sleeping. It also mentioned when things go missing or get moved it's them.

I really want to find the book again but all I can find is that Gnomes book that's a bit different. I remember reading novels and I am pretty sure it didn't have full colour pictures.

Please help!

Comment: Agreed, will send this over.

Comment: "As a kid" is an indeterminate time-frame, not knowing your age -- can you identify the year/decade you read them, and if they appeared new then?  Any other clues may help as well; any names you may remember, cover art, etc.

Comment: I'm 25, it would have been ~10 years ago at least. I don't remember names but I'm pretty sure they lived under floorboards and in garden sheds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Nome Trilogy by Terry Pratchett, (AKA The Bromeliad Trilogy) *Truckers*, *Diggers*, and *Wings*

> Nomes are small. On the whole, small creatures don’t live for a long
>   time. But perhaps they do live fast.
>
> Let me explain.
>
> One of the shortest-lived creatures on the planet Earth is the adult
>   common mayfly. It lasts for one day. The longest-living things are
>   bristlecone pine trees, at 4,700 years and still counting.
>
> This may seem tough on mayflies. But the important thing is not how
>   long your life is, but how long it seems.
>
> To a mayfly, a single hour may last as long as a century. Perhaps old
>   mayflies sit around complaining about how life this minute isn’t a
>   patch on the good old minutes of long ago, when the world was young
>   and the sun seemed so much brighter and larvae showed you a bit of
>   respect. Whereas the trees, which are not famous for their quick
>   reactions, may just have time to notice the way the sky keeps
>   flickering before the dry rot and woodworm set in.
>
> It’s all a sort of relativity. The faster you live, the more time
>   stretches out. To a nome, a year lasts as long as ten years does to a
>   human.
>
> Remember it. Don’t let it concern you. They don’t. They don’t even
>   know.

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: YES YES YES YES YES!!!!! Thank you SO MUCH!! I kept googling "Nome book" and "book about nomes" and stuff and was hopeless at finding it!! THANK YOU!!! :D